# Apply t.test on consecutive elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, rolling-computation

I have a vector that consists of n elements.

I am wondering how to do the following in an efficient manner (it is basically a rooling computation):

1. Extract elements with indices 1 to k
2. Extract elements with indices k+1 to 2k
3. perform a t.test on those elements
4. Extract elements with indices 2 to k+1
5. Extract elements with indices k+2 to 2k+1
6. perform a t.test on those elements
   ......
   7.Repeat until the end of the vector.

I do not need to see the extract values, just get some statistics (e.g. [1]$statistic).

I can do it with a loop but I am wondering how one could do it with some functions (eg. apply).
All the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear from your pseudo-code whether you really expected the vector to have n = 3 * k elements, but that's how I have programmed it.

```
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(15)

o = 1:5
k = 5

sapply(o, function(oi){
  x1 = x[oi:(k + oi - 1)]
  x2 = x[(k + oi):(2 * k + oi)]
  t.test(x1, x2)$statistic
})
```

and the result is

```
          t           t           t           t           t 
 0.04435004  1.28433640  1.67879015  0.11191044 -0.19398686
```

You could also work out some updating formulae for adding and subtracting a new element to each pair of vectors in the t-test, but it doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Looks like we hit on the same answer, seconds apart!

Comment: Yep :-) It's a snap

Comment: Thanks guys. Just perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sapply`, here wrapped in a function for clarity:

```r
multiple_ttest <- function(vec, k)
{
  sapply(seq(length(vec) - 2 * k), function(x){
    t.test(vec[x + 1:k], vec[x + (k + 1):(2 * k)])$statistic
  })
}

multiple_ttest(rnorm(100), 20)
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#> -0.6253586 -1.1680595 -1.2979357 -1.1051207 -1.4668645 -0.6156220 -0.2470322 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#> -1.2416802 -0.1763081 -0.1682269 -0.2490938  0.4569783  0.7721602  1.4383522 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#>  1.5530524  2.1523397  2.3221591  2.1876903  1.7248729  1.6149827  1.6919704 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#>  1.9747871  2.3833846  2.2826131  2.2337453  2.2225939  1.6284361  2.2067872 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#>  1.2447557  1.1435925  0.6731618 -0.1737223 -0.5889784 -0.7339752 -1.2202893 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#> -1.4936935 -1.5821069 -1.7795797 -1.6290700 -1.7760278 -1.4223367 -1.5931553 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#> -2.6832755 -2.7733223 -2.7710590 -3.0889778 -2.3604743 -2.3510220 -1.5456745 
#>          t          t          t          t          t          t          t 
#> -1.4098492 -0.5268468 -0.3187017  0.1878282  0.5208563  0.5656160  0.4952028 
#>          t          t          t          t 
#>  0.2005182  0.3769581  0.5093635  0.9358878
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>